# How do I build/run this simple Mahout program without getting exceptions?

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

I would like to run this code which I found in Mahout In Action:

```
package org.help;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.NamedVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;

public class SeqPrep {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        List<NamedVector> apples = new ArrayList<NamedVector>();

        NamedVector apple;

        apple = new NamedVector(new DenseVector(new double[]{0.11, 510, 1}), "small round green apple");        

        apples.add(apple);

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path path = new Path("appledata/apples");

        SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs,  conf, path, Text.class, VectorWritable.class);

        VectorWritable vec = new VectorWritable();
        for(NamedVector vector : apples){
            vec.set(vector);
            writer.append(new Text(vector.getName()), vec);
        }
        writer.close();

        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, new Path("appledata/apples"), conf);

        Text key = new Text();
        VectorWritable value = new VectorWritable();
        while(reader.next(key, value)){
            System.out.println(key.toString() + " , " + value.get().asFormatString());
        }
        reader.close();

    }

}
```

I compile it with:

```
$ javac -classpath :/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar:/home/hduser/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/hduser/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar:/home/hduser/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar -d myjavac/ SeqPrep.java
```

I jar it:

```
$ jar -cvf SeqPrep.jar -C myjavac/ .
```

Now I'd like to run it on my local hadoop node. I've tried:

```
 hadoop jar SeqPrep.jar org.help.SeqPrep
```

But I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/math/Vector
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

So I tried using the libjars parameter:

```
$ hadoop jar SeqPrep.jar org.help.SeqPrep -libjars /home/hduser/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar -libjars /home/hduser/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar -libjars /home/hduser/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar -libjars /home/hduser/mahout/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar -libjars /home/hduser/mahout/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
```

and got the same problem. I don't know what else to try.

My eventual goal is to be able to read a .csv file on the hadoop fs into a sparse matrix and then multiply it by a random vector.

**edit:** Looks like Razvan got it (note: see below for another way to do this that does not mess with your hadoop installation). For reference:

```
$ find /usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/. |grep mah
/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/./lib/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/./lib/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/./lib/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar
/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/./lib/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/./lib/mahout-math-0.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/./lib/mahout-math-0.8-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/./lib/mahout-math-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and then:

```
$hadoop jar SeqPrep.jar org.help.SeqPrep

small round green apple , small round green apple:{0:0.11,1:510.0,2:1.0}
```

**edit:**  I'm trying to do this without copying the mahout jars into the hadoop lib/

```
$ rm /usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/lib/mahout-*
```

and then of course:

```
hadoop jar SeqPrep.jar org.help.SeqPrep

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/math/Vector
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.Vector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

and when I try the mahout job file:

```
$hadoop jar ~/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.help.SeqPrep

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.help.SeqPrep
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

If I try to include the .jar file I made:

```
$ hadoop jar ~/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar SeqPrep.jar org.help.SeqPrep

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SeqPrep.jar
```

**edit:** Apparently I can only send one jar at a time to hadoop. This means I need to add the class I made into the mahout core job file:

```
~/mahout/trunk/core/target$ cp mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar_backup

~/mahout/trunk/core/target$ cp ~/workspace/seqprep/bin/org/help/SeqPrep.class .

~/mahout/trunk/core/target$ jar uf mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar SeqPrep.class
```

And then:

```
~/mahout/trunk/core/target$ hadoop jar mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.help.SeqPrep

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.help.SeqPrep
```

**edit:** Ok, now I can do it without messing with my hadoop installation. I was updating the .jar wrong in that previous edit. It should be:

```
~/mahout/trunk/core/target$ jar uf mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org/help/SeqPrep.class
```

then:

```
~/mahout/trunk/core/target$ hadoop jar mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.help.SeqPrep

small round green apple , small round green apple:{0:0.11,1:510.0,2:1.0}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the "job" JAR file provided by Mahout. It packages up all the dependencies. You need to add your classes to it too. This is how all the Mahout examples work. You shouldn't put Mahout jars in the Hadoop lib since that sort of "installs" a program too deeply in Hadoop.

Comment: "You need to use the "job" JAR file provided by Mahout." How do I do this?

Comment: Do you see the job file in the distribution? It's a JAR file but has "job" in the name. It gets created by `mvn package` in `target` in any event.

Comment: Ok, so what do I do with it? I'm trying hadoop jar ~/mahout/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.help.SeqPrep with no luck

Comment: Yes, that's it. What's not working now? this is the same as putting all the jars in the Hadoop installation, which is a no-no.

Comment: You haven't put your own classes into the one JAR you're feeding Hadoop. Add them to the job file. (Also I think there's a way to send multiple JARs to Hadoop and let it sort it out, but forget the syntax.)

Comment: Can you say a bit more? I'm as new to java as I am to hadoop/mahout. I've tried updating the mahout job jar with the .class file I made. Still no luck.

Comment: Are you sure? Use `jar tf` to look inside the JAR. It's just a zip file. You use the `jar` command to add files like `.class` files to it. It has to be in a dir that matches its package name.

Comment: "It has to be in a dir that matches its package name." -That did it. Thanks.

Comment: So, the way to write mahout code  is to update this job file when I write new classes? (I am interested in developing numerical linear algebra routines, I want mahout for it's existing linear algebra capabilities) Are there some other ways to do it that people commonly use?

Comment: Yes you can put together JAR files with Maven or Ant, rather than by hand. That's more typical, to have your build process make the complete JAR file.

Comment: another option to make this work without making a fat jar with all dependencies is to add DistributedCache.addArchiveToClassPath(new Path("/user/oozie/share/lib/java/mahout-core-0.7.0.1.3.2.0-110-job.jar"), conf, fs);  in you driver program. only problem is that jar paths might differ in different environment/clusters so take care of that. and obliviously you should put mahout jars on hdfs somewhere before doing this

Answer (score 7):

if you will take code for examples from https://github.com/tdunning/MiA repository, then it contains ready to use `pom.xml` file for Maven. And when you compile code with `mvn package`, then it will create `mia-0.1-job.jar` in the `target` directory - this archive contains all dependencies, except Hadoop's, so you can run it on Hadoop cluster without problems

Comment: thanks, I was not using Maven when I started out with Mahout and posted this question. By now, I've learned about Maven and can't imagine how I ever did anything without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please provide a little more information about what this answer does, how to apply it, or why it's an answer. Or you're likely to get downvoted or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH with my jar and all the mahout jar files
as shown below.

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/xxx/my.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-core-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-core-0.7-cdh4.3.0-job.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-cdh4.3.0-job.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-integration-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-math-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar

Then I was able to run
hadoop com.mycompany.mahout.CSVtoVector iris/nb/iris1.csv iris/nb/data/iris.seq

So you have to include all your jars and the mahout jar in the HADOOP_CLASSPATH and then you can just run your class with
hadoop `<classname>`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get Sean's answer to work. However, I eventually learned Maven to solve this. I suggest doing it that way.