# Vectorization in Apache Mahout

Tags: apache, hadoop, classification, vectorization, mahout

I am new to Mahout. I have a requirement to convert a text file to a vector for classification in  later stage.

Could anybody of of shed some light on these below questions?

1. How to convert a text file to a vector in mahout?
   The file format is like "username|comment about item|rating"
2. The data will be few TBs. So which algorithm implementable I can use for classification using the vector I suppose to create?

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check these 2 examples that also somewhat do/explain how to use the Sequence File API. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645294/how-can-i-use-mahouts-sequencefile-api-code/11645430#11645430) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479600/runing-a-simple-mahout-program)

And you should definitely read this [***intro***](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/quick-tour-of-text-analysis-using-the-mahout-command-line.html) to text analysis