# Converting CSV to SequenceFile

Tags: hadoop, mahout, sequencefile

I have a CSV file which I would like to convert to a SequenceFile, which I would ultimately use to create NamedVectors to use in a clustering job. I've been using the seqdirectory command to try to make a SequenceFile, and then fed that output into seq2sparse with the -nv option to create NamedVectors. It seems like this is giving one big vector as an output, but I ultimately want each line of my CSV to become a NamedVector. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seqdirectory` command takes every file as a document, so in reality, you only have one document, hence you only get one vector. To make it work properly you would make each line of your CSV file a file itself, where the **key** of the document is the name of the file and the **value** are its content. Nonetheless, this is quite unpractical if your corpus is large as disk reading and writing can become painfully slow.

In practice you are better off following the links I share in this [***comment***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11948318/863772)

Comment: Great, thank you for your help. I will check out those links.