# Mahout: converting one large text file to SequenceFile format

Tags: java, mahout, sequencefile

I have done a lot of searching on the web for this, but I've found nothing, even though I feel like it has to be somewhat common.  I have used Mahout's seqdirectory command to convert a folder containing text files (each file is a separate document) in the past.  But in this case there are so many documents (in the 100,000s) that I have one very large text file in which each line is a document.  How can I convert this large file to SequenceFile format so that Mahout understands that each line should be considered a separate document?  Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting CSV to SequenceFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994930/converting-csv-to-sequencefile)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is not quite apparent or very intuitive how to do this, although (lucky for you :P) I have answered that exact question several times here in stack, for instance [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994930/converting-csv-to-sequencefile/12001297#12001297). Have a look ;)