# Running Mahout Job on Hadoop: Got ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, mahout, cloudera

I try to run a Mahout Kmeans Example on the cloudera quickstart vm for hadoop. I read here [link to clouudera block](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) and here [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139774/classnotfoundexception-org-apache-mahout-math-vectorwritable) that i can use the -libjars command to attach the mahout .jars

I put the jar-files: KMeansHadoop.jar mahout-core-0.9.jar and mahout-math-0.9.jar in the same folder and run:

hadoop jar KMeansHadoop.jar SimpleKMeansClustering -libjars mahout-core-0.9.jar mahout-math-0.9.jar

But i still get the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/math/Vector

What do i wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe that the `-libjars` values need to be **comma-separated**. But that only makes your third-party jars available to the cluster. You may also need to use `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to make those jars available on the client side (e.g: on the edge node from which you're kicking off your job).

Check out [this post](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/). It helped me a lot when I was working my way through this exact issue with getting Driven to work with Cascading.